# Reduce a php background image with CSS

Tags: php, css, background, resize

The image has the right size when the display is bigger than 320px.

However, if I use a smaller display, the Background image in the circle won't resize and I will loose part of the image under the smaller circle.

```css
.ch-grid-variant li {
  width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 330px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.ch-item-variant {
  width: 118%;
  height: 118%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid #1B4046;
  position: relative;
  cursor: default;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(200, 95, 66, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.ch-img-x-variant {
  background-size: 260px 260px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 260px;
}
.ch-img-x-variant img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  text-align: center;
}
.ch-info-variant {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /*for a smooth font */
}
.ch-item-variant:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 130px rgba(200, 95, 66, 0.4), inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.ch-item-variant:hover .ch-info-variant {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
.ch-info-variant h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 65px 0 0 0;
  height: 80px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.ch-info-variant p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
/* smaller than 320px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .ch-item-variant {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: -1px;
  }
  .ch-img-x-variant {
    background-size: 220px 220px;
    height: 220px;
  }
  .ch-img-x-variant img {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="ch-grid-variant">
  <li id="services_box_container1">
    <div class="ch-item-variant ch-img-x-variant" style="background: url(http://sandiegosids.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Daly_Web_Banner-260px-CTA.jpg);">
      <div class="ch-info-wrap">
        <div class="ch-info-variant">
          <div class="ch-info-front ch-img-x-variant">
            <h3>text</h3>
            <p>undertext</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I thought changing the "background-size" in the CSS would do the trick but it doesn't....

What do I do wrong?

Thanks a lot!

PS: The background url is hard-linked for the example but in reality the field is filled with a "php echo" variable.

Comment: Did you try `background-size: contain;`?

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Give it in style attribute.  `style="background: url(http://sandiegosids.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Daly_Web_Banner-260px-CTA.jpg); background-size: contain;"`

Comment: It works in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5q8thwf/)

Comment: Perfect !!! yes it works !! 
I was trying to do it through CSS.... 

Thanks !!!!

Comment: It would work with CSS but you are overwriting with inline style. If you want through CSS then in style instead of `background:` give `background-image`

Comment: Correct!  swapping `background:` with  `background-image` makes it work too! I understand where the problem was now :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background property in your inline style sets the `background-size` property, therefore it overrides any `background-size` from your style sheet:

```
background: [color] [image] [repeat] [position] [size];
```

The easiest way around this if you want to use a media query would be to use `!important` in your code:

```
background-size: 220px 220px !important;
```

or you could use contain with it as as well:

```
background-size: contain !important;
```

`!important` can make things messy, so use it with caution, but if your image needs to be dynamically set, it may be the way to go.

The other option is to include the `background-size` in your inline-style, where it has the same precedence.

Comment: Thanks Greg! As you said, `!important` is a bit messy and I try to avoid it. I followed the answer from @anpsmn by swapping `background:` with `background-image:` in the inline style and have `background-size: contain` in my CSS. 
Your answer greatly helped my understanding.